# Vertically aligned image and text div

Tags: html, css

> UPDATE: The answers have got me close, but they still don't align vertically as the text div is larger, how can I make them both the same height and therefore align?

I would like to have two DIVs next to each other, one containing an image and one containing text, both sitting in a container DIV.

The image should be 15% of the width of the container div, with the text using the remaining 85%

The image and text should be aligned vertically within their respective DIVs, so it looks like they are aligned with each other.

I've tried to work this out but can't seem to do it! Can anyone help?

```
#picture {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    line-height: auto;
}

#text {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 16%;
    line-height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

#text p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

and

```
 <div id="quotes">
    <div id="picture">
        <img style="width: 100%; vertical-align: middle" src="tom.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <p>"Christiaan was one of the stand out candidates throughout, therefore there was no hesitation in offering him a place on this highly sort after scheme..."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code for what you've tried.

Comment: `I've tried to work this` show us what you try.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with your code in it: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ6Vw/1/

The only changes I made was to assign matching top/bottom margins to the `img` and `p` tags. I think that will give you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: +1 thx for the jsfiddle, but not for the code float & vertical align are not friendly use together.

Answer (score 1):

If you use float and verticl-align, those two won'nt work together.
Float extract itself from regular flow and go slide on one side or the other on top of next line right after any content within the regular flow.

Vertical-align works:

1. in betweem inline-boxes (inline-block-level element or displayed so with `display:inline-block;`)
2. inside td or it's CSS default display : `display:table-cell;`

   here jsfiddle @TXChetG updated
3. Using `display:inline-block;` http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/hQ6Vw/2/
4. Using `display:table/* table-cell*/;`
   http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/hQ6Vw/3/

Comment: The only correction I would make, since you have padding is to reduce the width percentages to < 100% (to something like 98%) as sizing may cause the text to appear under the image.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close:

```
<div>
    <div style="background: grey; width: 15%; float:left"></div>
    <div style="background: blue; width: 85%; float:left"></div>
</div>
```

Replace the grey background div with your image and the blue with your text.

Comment: this is close, but the image and text don't align as they are different heights, any way to fix this?

Comment: If you know the heights of your content, you can set static heights on the Divs and they should align.

Comment: They're not going to be static, the height of the image div should match the height of the text div, with the image centered vertically

Comment: if both heights should match, then use display:table/table-cell, you might vertical-align text and /or image within their respective containers.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Gsj27/3/)

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
div#two {
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="background-color:black">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Example
  </div>
</div>   
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="background-color:black">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Example
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  clear: both;
}
.images {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.text {
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
  vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the `#text p` display to `display: inline` or `display:block;` or use margins to align them?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="quotes">
    <div id="picture">
        <img src="tom.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <p>"Christiaan was one of the stand out candidates throughout, therefore there was no hesitation in offering him a place on this highly sort after scheme..."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Display the container div as table and the text and image divs as table-cell to make them the same heights. You can then centre the image vertically through vertical-align:middle.

```
#quotes {
    display:table;
}
#picture {
    width: 15%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#text {
    display:table-cell;
    width:85%;
    padding-left: 16%;
}
#picture img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X3WsV/1/